# Redirect audio output on Android

Tags: android, redirect, audio

on Samsung Galaxy S8 with Andtoid Oreo there is an equalizer, that gets applied on all media output (not sure about other outputs like calls, I need just media).

I am currently writing a music player in Java and I would like to know, whether it is possible to redirect all media output into an app to process the sound like the EQ on S8 does.

Edit: The actual question is how to do it and if I need a superuser (root) for that. From which Android version is this possible?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about, but if you see the feature on the S8 then you know it's possible. How to do it is a completely different question.

Comment: I am sorry. I am kinda tired now. But yes, that is the actual question.

Samsung changed a lot of Android's functionality and settings. I wanted to know, whether it is possible to do it with a simple app and if yes, then how and from which Android version is this possible?